# Returning local position as color

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

I am trying to pass the local position of an object from vertex to fragment shader in Unity to encode it later in a rendertexture.

```
    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag


        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct MeshData
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
        };

        struct Interpolators
        {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float3 objectVertex : TEXCOORD0;
        };

       Interpolators vert (MeshData v)
        {
            Interpolators o;
            o.objectVertex = v.vertex.xyz;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            return o;
        }

         fixed4 frag (Interpolators i) : SV_Target
        {
            return  float4(i.objectVertex,1);  
        }
        ENDCG
    }
```

The result I want to achieve is on the right, my result is on the left:

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you sure the object coordinates are as you expect? The front corner isn't -1,-1,-1 instead of 0,0,0?

Comment: I think one useful piece of information I forgot to mention is that I use front culling.

Comment: well then the back corner